# Check the subcollection exists before query in firestore

Tags: swift, database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm implementing a social media app, where I put a subcollection of "following" under each user. I want to check if the subcollection exists before I query the subcollection, or the app will crash for querying a nonexistent collection. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: hmm i ended up saving a field in the document with a boolean of if the subcollection exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections don't really "exist" in the way that you're thinking.  They simply appear when the first document is created, and they disappear when the last document is removed.  There is no operation to simply create or remove a collection like a folder in a filesystem, and there is not operation to check to see if a collection "exists".  A query against a collection with no documents will not fail (unless it was rejected by a security rule).

The only thing you can really do is query the collection to see if it has any documents at all.  You can limit the query to 1 document if you want to minimize costs.